# How to find the total distance traveled by the particle when given the velocity function?

Tags: calculus

I found the problem in Practice Exam (AP Calculus AB in 2008) 
A particle moves along the x-axis so that its velocity at any time $t \ge 0$ is given by $v(t)=5te^{-t}-1.$ At $t=0,$ the particle is at position $x=1$. What is the total distance traveled by the particle from $t=0$ to $t=4$? 
(A) 0.366
(B) 0.542
(C) 1.542
(D) 1.821
(E) 2.821 
I had position function $x(t)=x(0)+\int^t_0v(s)ds=-5te^{-t}-5e^{-t}+5-t+1$ 
I know that "total distance traveled" equals $\int^4_0|v(t)|dt$, but I can't solve the equation $v(t)=0$.

Comment: Think about Lambert function or plot $v(t)$

Comment: OP probably does not not what Lambert functions are. This answer is unhelpful and pretentious.